# Eclipse cannot find JDK

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse

I'm installing Eclipse (adt-bundle-linux-x86_64).  I placed the files in my /opt/ folder and when I try to run eclipse it give me a pop up saying

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

So I attempted to add the java path to the eclipse.ini file by adding

> -vm /opt/jdk1.80_20/bin/java

But I still get the same error pop up (it didn't change at all, I expected it to say the path I added to the .ini file but it stayed the same.)

I then tried to create a symbolic link in the /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/jre/bin/ folder pointing to /opt/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/bin/java and it now gives me a new pop up saying

```
>JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/jre/bin/java
-vm /opt/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 330012
-product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-vm /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-vm /opt/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

I have two questions:
1. Why does adding the line to the eclipse.ini file not change the path
2. How do I set the correct path for eclipse to run?

Thanks

Comment: The -vm and the /opt/... must be on separate lines in the eclipse.ini

Comment: I did try that as well but the same issue. I haven't tried @Luis Matos's solution yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps outlined in http://www.blogs.digitalworlds.net/softwarenotes/?p=54 after deleting and reinstalling the JDK and deleting Eclipse.  I still got the pop-up error but I created a symbolic link at the path it requested pointing to Java

```
ln -s /opt/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/bin/java jre/bin/java
```

This finally worked to get Eclipse to run.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess, to read the eclipse.ini file you would already have to be running something. And that would be the java executable.

Did you try to:

set JAVA_HOME to the address you have your java environment, and
set your PATH variable to include java home, like set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/%PATH% ?

Comment: I tried that and still get the same pop up as before.  It didn't seem to make a difference